# Failing to execute transactions via subxt on a substrate chain

Tags: subxt

I am trying to use subxt (latest master branch) to submit transactions on our substrate chain. I get the following error:

```
 actix_web::middleware::logger] Error in response: SubxtError(Rpc(ClientError(Call(Custom(ErrorObject { code: ServerError(1002), message: "Verification Error: Runtime error: Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed\nWASM backtrace:\nerror while executing at wasm backtrace:\n    0: 0x17a85a - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind\n    1: 0x161756 - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::h55a9886e2bf4227a\n    2: 0x6b01a - <unknown>!TaggedTransactionQueue_validate_transaction", data: Some(RawValue("RuntimeApi(\"Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed\\nWASM backtrace:\\nerror while executing at wasm backtrace:\\n    0: 0x17a85a - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind\\n    1: 0x161756 - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::h55a9886e2bf4227a\\n    2: 0x6b01a - <unknown>!TaggedTransactionQueue_validate_transaction\")")) })))))
```

The same transactions work just fine from https://polkadot.js.org/
RPC query methods are also working fine via subxt.

Comment: provide reproducible example

Comment: what is the transaction?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by using the subxt provided `PolkadotConfig` rather than my custom config that was based on `SubstrateConfig`. There must be some differences I was not able to determine relating to extrinsic validation.

Answer (score 1):

Glad you figure it out!

We are also providing an example [here](https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/master/examples/examples/setup_client_custom_config.rs) on how to setup a custom client `Config`.

Although, we encourage the users first to try the `Polkadot`/`Substrate` config. If that doesn't work, go one step lower in the stack, and implement their own config when targeting some custom chains (ie, parachains that differ from the configs we provide).

One tricky area around having a custom config may be the `type ExtrinsicParams`, but in practice, any other fields can diverge.